# Find best intervall to do a fit of data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, minimize

I have data that comes from numerical simulations (around 7000 points, more in other simulations), this data is plotted in the image bellow. As you can see it has a small interval (between 0.35 and 0.45) where this data is linear (it is theoretically linear on that region, but also i measured it and indeed it is in that region).

I want to calculate the best interval where the slope/fit is maximal/best automatically.

For the moment i do it by hand, i chose by eye an interval, then calculate the fit. Then repeat until i find a slope/fit that looks good (This is what i did for this image).

[image]

I know this can be done by brute force by calculating all possible intervals in my data and comparing the slopes. However i want to doit a little more intelligently.

I tried to do it whit scipy minimize, since this is a function i have used multiple times and know how to use it. For this i take my data and pass it to `miminize`, with hoppes that it will search for 2 numbers the min and max of the interval.

I tried by searching for the values on x (ie 0.35 and 0.45), and also the index of the data (ie 3000 and 3700). As follows,

```
Mini = minimize(wrapper(MinFit, x_dat, y_dat), (0,nPoints), method='Powell')
def wrapper(func, x, y):
    def newfunc(t):
        return func(*t, x, y)
    return(newfunc)
def MinFit(iMin, iMax, x_dat, y_dat):
    iMin, iMax = np.int(np.ceil(np.abs(iMin))), np.int(np.ceil(np.abs(iMax)))
    if(iMin == iMax):
        print('i = ', iMin, iMax)
        FitParam = [0., 0.]
    else:
        Min, Max = np.min([x_dat[iMin], x_dat[iMax]]), np.max([x_dat[iMin], x_dat[iMax]])
        print('i = ', iMin, iMax)
        print(x_dat[iMin], x_dat[iMax])
        x_dat_short, y_dat_short = CutData(x_dat, y_dat, Max, Min)
        FitParam, FitCovar = curve_fit(Linear, x_dat_short, y_dat_short, p0=(0,0), maxfev= 5000)
    return(-FitParam[0])
```

Where `MinFit` is a function that takes 4 inputs `(indexMin, indexMax, x_data, y_data)`, `wrapper` just an intermediary function to properly use `minimize` (reduce inputs to the once i want to search) and `nPoints` is the index of the last data point.

However the code properly calculates the first iteration and then it breaks (for both index and float search) and outputs the following error:

```
Mini = minimize(wrapper(MinFit, x_dat, y_dat), (0,nPoints), method='Powell')                                                                          
i =  0 58333
0.0 0.699996
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-295df9b333b7> in <module>
----> 1 Mini = minimize(wrapper(MinFit, x_dat, y_dat), (0,nPoints), method='Powell')

/.../_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    588         return _minimize_neldermead(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
    589     elif meth == 'powell':
--> 590         return _minimize_powell(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
    591     elif meth == 'cg':
    592         return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)

/.../optimize.py in _minimize_powell(func, x0, args, callback, xtol, ftol, maxiter, maxfev, disp, direc, return_all, **unknown_options)
   2610             fx2 = fval
   2611             fval, x, direc1 = _linesearch_powell(func, x, direc1,
-> 2612                                                  tol=xtol * 100)
   2613             if (fx2 - fval) > delta:
   2614                 delta = fx2 - fval

/.../optimize.py in _linesearch_powell(func, p, xi, tol)
   2396     def myfunc(alpha):
   2397         return func(p + alpha*xi)
-> 2398     alpha_min, fret, iter, num = brent(myfunc, full_output=1, tol=tol)
   2399     xi = alpha_min*xi
   2400     return squeeze(fret), p + xi, xi

/.../optimize.py in brent(func, args, brack, tol, full_output, maxiter)
   2107     options = {'xtol': tol,
   2108                'maxiter': maxiter}
-> 2109     res = _minimize_scalar_brent(func, brack, args, **options)
   2110     if full_output:
   2111         return res['x'], res['fun'], res['nit'], res['nfev']

/.../optimize.py in _minimize_scalar_brent(func, brack, args, xtol, maxiter, **unknown_options)
   2139                   full_output=True, maxiter=maxiter)
   2140     brent.set_bracket(brack)
-> 2141     brent.optimize()
   2142     x, fval, nit, nfev = brent.get_result(full_output=True)
   2143     return OptimizeResult(fun=fval, x=x, nit=nit, nfev=nfev,

/.../optimize.py in optimize(self)
   1923         # set up for optimization
   1924         func = self.func
-> 1925         xa, xb, xc, fa, fb, fc, funcalls = self.get_bracket_info()
   1926         _mintol = self._mintol
   1927         _cg = self._cg

/.../optimize.py in get_bracket_info(self)
   1897         ### carefully DOCUMENT any CHANGES in core ##
   1898         if brack is None:
-> 1899             xa, xb, xc, fa, fb, fc, funcalls = bracket(func, args=args)
   1900         elif len(brack) == 2:
   1901             xa, xb, xc, fa, fb, fc, funcalls = bracket(func, xa=brack[0],

/.../optimize.py in bracket(func, xa, xb, args, grow_limit, maxiter)
   2322     _gold = 1.618034  # golden ratio: (1.0+sqrt(5.0))/2.0
   2323     _verysmall_num = 1e-21
-> 2324     fa = func(*(xa,) + args)
   2325     fb = func(*(xb,) + args)
   2326     if (fa < fb):                      # Switch so fa > fb

/.../optimize.py in myfunc(alpha)
   2395     """
   2396     def myfunc(alpha):
-> 2397         return func(p + alpha*xi)
   2398     alpha_min, fret, iter, num = brent(myfunc, full_output=1, tol=tol)
   2399     xi = alpha_min*xi

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple
```

(I deleted the paths for privacy reasons and put `...`)

Is there a way to do what i want? Can `minimize` do it? If so how?

Second question, is there a way to constrain scipy `minimize`? (ie. only search for values between `a=1` and `b=nPoints`, or any other value and type)

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the approach to evaluate the residuals (model - datapoints) and set some threshold for datapoints you want to consider?

Comment: can you explain more? The residuals is the matrix curve_fit outputs right? Doing that will just be brute force isn't it?, the thing i don't want to do (unless is the only option)

Comment: No, residual as the difference in y between the calculated value of y (using the regression formula that you obtained by fitting) and the datapoint y, for the x of the datapoint....you then return the x values where the delta y is too big (let's say one standard deviation away from the mean of the delta y-s. The residuals should also be returned when you apply the curve_fit function.

Comment: Ok i understand. Now the question is how to obtain the right/good/best regression formula? I want to automate, therefore i want to just give the code the data, then it will output 1 regression formula (the best one).